# Source Computer name in custom logs collected by Azure Monitor Agent

Tags: azure-log-analytics, azure-monitoring

I have set up Azure Monitor custom log collection on my Linux VM by [following the tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/agents/data-collection-text-log)  and all works fine, except that the `Computer Name` column in my custom table does not get populated. This means I have no easy way to distinguish between similar logs sourced from multiple VMs.

I could probably hack in the hostname into the log file itself and get Azure to parse it into a field, but on one hand I don't want to customize the log file if possible, I believe the agent should be capable of propagating this information somehow.

Is there anything that needs to be configured outside of the tutorial, or is it a current limitation of the Azure Monitor Agent?

Comment: Hi Jabal, did you manage to sort this out with the computer name? Currently, I am having the same issue getting the computer name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed in 2023 Feb by Microsoft: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/951629/custom-logs-hostname-field-azure-monitoring-agent